# how to add hint of AppCompatSpinner

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Well first of all This is not **android.widget.Spinner** it's **AppCompatSpinner**

how to add hint of `AppCompatSpinner` i'm getting a `string-array` from `String.xml`

So my question is how to i take 1st `String` as a `Hint`

Below `layout.xml` file :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
                    android:id="@+id/spStates"
                    style="@style/TextLabelBookBlack"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_4sdp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_4sdp"
                    android:entries="@array/us_states"
                    android:scrollbars="none"/>
```

Below is `String.xml`

```
<string-array name="us_states">
        <item>States</item>
        <item>Alabama,AL</item>
        <item>Alaska,AK</item>
        <item>American Samoa,AS</item>
        <item>Arizona,AZ</item>
        <item>Arkansas,AR</item>
        <item>California,CA</item>
        <item>Colorado,CO</item>
        <item>Connecticut,CT</item>
</string-array>
```

in `String.xml` 1st item is `States` so i want to take `States` as a hint so how to i take it.

Comment: i declare a 1st its not a `android.widget.Spinner` @SachinVarma

Comment: spinner have no hint, you can disable first position programmatically.

Comment: add hint in string-array item first position and handle condition in onItemSelectedListener()

Comment: and `android.widget.Spinner` or `AppCompatSpinner` same or different @HemantParmar

Comment: Both are different.

Comment: you can use Material spinner for set hint, have look [MaterialSpinner](https://github.com/ganfra/MaterialSpinner)

Comment: Spinner/AppCompatSpinner does not support hint. 1) Put a [label](https://material.io/guidelines/components/text-fields.html#text-fields-layout) above it if you have to and 2) preselect a reasonable default in the spinner.

Comment: But you can disable first item click programetically then why you are not doing that ??

Comment: `AppCompatSpinner extends android.widget.Spinner `.... So **it is** the other Spinner by definition. Read the docs or the source code https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v7/appcompat/src/main/java/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatSpinner.java#L68

Comment: Are bhai me kidhu em kro to pn thy jase.

Comment: ok i'll try pragmatically @SahdevRajput74

Comment: There is no hint support in Spinner . A `TextView` with `PopUpWindow` can provide same appearance . And FYI `Spinner` and `AppCompatSpinner` both are almost same.

Comment: Also, as the documentation says *[`AppCompatSpinner`] will automatically be used when you use `Spinner` in your layouts. You should only need to manually use this class when writing custom views*

Comment: No thay to kejo me krelu che evu hu example aapis tmne

Comment: Ya sure i'll try my best first if show the error then i'll change my question ok @SahdevRajput74

Comment: yap all the best!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can use an edit text and set a hint to it..when users select an item display it in the edit text ..just keep the spinner below the edit text in xml file ...and fire onclick event of spinner when clicked on edit text(basically you just need to hide/show the dropdown)

Comment: In this case the user would still be able to type into it though.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in the `prompt` attribute of the `Spinner` class.